# How does displaying of human readable Byte-Sizes work?

Tags: powershell

Suppose the following output of `Get-Disk`:

```
PS C:\own\powershell> Get-Disk

Number Friendly Name Serial Number                    HealthStatus         OperationalStatus      Total Size Partition
                                                                                                         Style
------ ------------- -------------                    ------------         -----------------      ---------- ----------
0      Crucial_CT... (removed)                        Healthy              Online                  931.51 GB MBR
1      Crucial_CT... (removed)                        Healthy              Online                    1.86 TB MBR
9      LaCie Rugg... (removed)                        Healthy              Online                    1.82 TB GPT
```

Because I want to display an additional column in the front, I tried the following:

```
PS C:\own\powershell> Get-Disk | ft BusType, FriendlyName, SerialNumber, HealthStatus, OperationalStatus, TotalSize, PartitionStyle

BusType FriendlyName              SerialNumber  HealthStatus OperationalStatus TotalSize PartitionStyle
------- ------------              ------------  ------------ ----------------- --------- --------------
SATA    Crucial_CT1024MX200SSD1   (removed)     Healthy      Online                      MBR
SATA    Crucial_CT2050MX300SSD1   (removed)     Healthy      Online                      MBR
USB     LaCie Rugged USB-C        (removed)     Healthy      Online                      GPT
```

However, there a some subtle points, I don't understand:

- The most important one: The TotalSize column is empty. If I just use `Size` instead of `TotalSize` the size is shown in Bytes - but not in human readable format like "1.86 TB". Why is that? How does it automagically work when I just type `Get-Disk`?
- In the first output, the column is named "Friendly Name" (with space). When I specify `"Friendly Name"` for `ft`, it won't work. When I use `FriendlyName`, it works - but obviously the header will be shown without spaces. How does this work automatically for plain `Get-Disk`?
- In the first example, the output uses the width of the view - but not in the second one. (Despite the `Format-Table` docs stating that "By default, the column size and number are determined by the view." See the `-Autosize` parameter in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-6 )

And the final question: How can I get the output I want (with the additional column AND the disk size in human readable format)?

I already checked the `.ps1xml` files in `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` but could not find an entry for the output of `Get-Disk`.

Comment: the output is in a format dictated by the format file for that type. i don't have Get-Disk [it is not included with win7ps5.1], so i can't tell you what file it is stored in. ///// if you want to customize the column names and content, you will need to either generate a custom object with those properties OR use Select-Object and create calculated properties.

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAl - is there a easy way I can reuse this definition and just add my additional column?

Comment: `@{Label="TotalSize";Expr={[math]::Round(($_.Size/1Gb))}}` instead of `TotalSize`. See e.g. [Using PowerShell's Calculated Properties](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/01/19/using-powershell-calculated-properties.aspx)